# Windows 10 - remote procedure call failed when starting task manager/mmc or anything that requires UAC

Tags: windows-10, uac

I have a domain account on Windows 10, without administrator permissions. This means that to open Task Manager, UAC pops up and I have to enter my password. However, Task Manager won't open and neither will any of the mmc consoles (e.g. Hyper-V, Services, etc) nor command prompt when I try to run it as administrator. They all fail giving the "remote procedure call failed" error.

If I have admin rights on this domain user, everything works fine. I tried checking RPC Service (both local and the remote one), changing Windows Sound scheme (found this somewhere to be the culprit) and the problem persists. My IT department claims the only way to fix this is to reinstall Windows but I'd rather avoid it if possible.

Comment: So what is your question. It sounds like you have neither a Administrator access on the domain nor are you a local Administrator on the machine

Comment: My question is what can be done to fix the issue. I have a local admin account which can grant admin rights to the domain user for a limited time, to resolve this issue.

Comment: A local Administrator account cannot grant permissions to a domain account.  Your local Administrator account does not exist on the domain.  It wouldn't have the permissions on the domain to do what you just said.

Comment: It can an it does. I add my domain user to the Administrators group through Users/Roles snap in in MMC. It asks for a domain username and password to check the username on the domain though.

Comment: So you are adding your domain User to the local machine's Administrator user group.  That isn't what you just indicated you were doing though.  You indicated you were going to use your local Administrator account, to grant permissions, to your domain user account.  You still have not modified your question, so your question itself, indicates what your question actually is.  Honestly, what your issue is, isn't even all that clear.  Which is the reason you have 2 votes to close this question for being unclear.